# How do I use a class variable in the function() method?

Tags: function, typescript

Class Variable Name: addPointY

"addPointY" Using Function:

```
setInterval(function () {
    var y = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
    series.addPoint(this.addPointY, true, true);
}, 3000);
```

---

I have to find a way to use it.
This is a customer requirement and has not been resolved.
Please tell me another way.

The class variable must be used in any of its methods.
But I could not get the class variable.

Do not you have a smart developer who solved the same problem?

---

```
@Injectable()
export class HighChartService implements ChartService {
private addPointY: number = 0;

shiftAddPoint(data: number) {
    this.addPointY = data;
    console.log(this.addPointY);
}

/**
* @see DynamicChart start function
* @param obj chart Object
* @param title Top Title
* @param type ChartType
* @param yAxisTitle Left Title
* @param series Chart data
* @author jskang
* @since  2017/10/12
*/
dynamicInitOptions(title: string, type: string, yAxisTitle: string, series: Object[]) {
    if (!type) { type = "line"; }
    let obj = new Chart({
        chart: {
            type: type,
            events: {
                load: function () {
                    // set up the updating of the chart each second
                    var series = this.series[0];
                    setInterval(function () {
                        var y = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
                        series.addPoint(this.addPointY, true, true);
                    }, 3000);
                }
            }
        },
        title: { text: title },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6],
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    let xAxis = "";
                    if(this.value % 7 == 0){ xAxis = "일"; }
                    else if(this.value % 7 == 1){ xAxis = "월"; }
                    else if(this.value % 7 == 2){ xAxis = "화"; }
                    else if(this.value % 7 == 3){ xAxis = "수"; }
                    else if(this.value % 7 == 4){ xAxis = "목"; }
                    else if(this.value % 7 == 5){ xAxis = "금"; }
                    else if(this.value % 7 == 6){ xAxis = "토"; }
                    return xAxis;
                }
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: yAxisTitle
            },
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return this.value;
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle'
        },
        series: series
    });
    return obj;
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `this` inside your callback function for `setInterval` does not point to the current class instance because when you use `function () {}` syntax it creates its own binding for `this` based on how it is called.

To fix this use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which preserves the context and you can access your class properties inside the callback:

```
load: () => { // Notice arrow function here
    // set up the updating of the chart each second
    var series = this.series[0];
    setInterval(() => { // Notice arrow function here
        var y = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
        series.addPoint(this.addPointY, true, true);
    }, 3000);
}
```

---

Another way you can solve this is by using the `that` pattern where you capture your `this` where it points to your class instance and use it wherever you need to refer to your instance:

```
dynamicInitOptions(title: string, type: string, yAxisTitle: string, series: Object[]) {
    if (!type) { type = "line"; }
    let that = this; // Capture `this` here
    let obj = new Chart({
        chart: {
            type: type,
            events: {
                load: function () {
                    // set up the updating of the chart each second
                    var series = this.series[0];
                    setInterval(function () {
                        var y = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
                        series.addPoint(that.addPointY, true, true); // Use `that` instead of `this here
                    }, 3000);
                }
            }
        }
        // ...
    });
}
```